# zsh keybind giving error it isn't a widget

Tags: command-line-interface, zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc, fzf

I am trying to create a keybind that maps to a function. whenever I call the function from the terminal it works perfectly but whenever I use my keybind it doesn't and I get this error: No such widget `fzf-cd'. this is my code

```
function fzf-cd() {
  local dir=$(find . -type d -print | fzf)
  if [[ -n "$dir" ]]; then
    cd "$dir"
    echo "Switched to: $dir"
  else
    echo "No directory chosen."
  fi
}

bindkey "\ef" fzf-cd
```

I've trying to change the keybind to something else but that doesn't really help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it myself, but I'm pretty certain that you need to register your function as widget before you can use it in zle:

```
zle -N fzf-cd
```

However, the content of your function `fcf-cd` function looks a bit  strange to me for the use as a zle widget. The purpose of widgets is to act as kind of "programmable macros", and I would expect your function to at least simulate other key presses.

Answer (score 0):

From `zshzle`(1):

> ZLE WIDGETS
>
> All actions in the editor are performed by `widgets'.  ... The ZLE commands that key sequences in keymaps are bound to are in fact widgets.  Widgets can be user-defined or built in. ...
>
> User-defined widgets are defined using `zle -N`, and implemented as shell functions.  When the widget is executed, the corresponding shell function is executed, and can perform editing (or other) actions.

In other words, the “command” for `bindkey` must be a widget, not a function, and you turn a function into a widget using `zle -N`, in your case `zle -N fzf-cd`.